# Make an equation in php

Tags: php, equation

I have a php file where i want to make an equation with the output i get.

It is pretty easy if the line is like this:

```
 <?php echo round(($post['voteup']/($post['voteup'] + $post['votedown'] ))*100); ?>
```

But i have a php line where it goes like this, and i just can't figure out how to make the equation work:

```
 $str='';
 $data = $dbc->query($sql);
 if($data!=null && $data->num_rows>0){
 while( $row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

 $str.="<p>".$row['voteup']."  +  ".$row['votedown'].</p>";
 }
```

It may be a silly question, but this really bothers me.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "make an equation"?  Are you trying to output and actual equation in the browser or simply make some calculation?

Comment: Why can't you just rename `$post` to `$row` and replace echo with `$str += `?

Comment: It is just an example.     Jay  just made the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the upvotes and downvotes you would do this -

```
$newTotal = $row['voteup'] + $row['votedown'];
$str.="<p>" . $newTotal ."</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what i was looking for.  You will get my high five in 9 min

Comment: High five and hang ten.

Comment: This seems to fix OP's problem, but I would suggest to OP to simply change the query to do the summation in the query itself if you have no need for the individual column values when working with the query results.

Comment: Ah, yes @MikeBrant - that would be the best solution unless the OP needs/wants to use the values individually on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add `$row['voteup']` and `$row['votedown']` together you should addition them in a variable first then use it.

```php
$total = $row['voteup'] + $row['votedown'];
$str .= "<p>{$total}</p>";
```

If you really need to make it inline you can do something like this as well.

```php
$str .= '<p>' . ($row['voteup'] + $row['votedown']) . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the "equation" simply fix the error.

```
$str.="<p>".$row['voteup']."  +  ".$row['votedown']."</p>";
```

Or you could actually turn it into an equation:

```
$str.="<p>".$row['voteup']."  +  ".$row['votedown']." = ".($row['voteup'] + $row['votedown'])."</p>";
```